# Python debugging, stop at particular output

Tags: python, debugging, logging

I have complex python project with lots of modules, loggers, twisted defereds and other stuff.

And somewhere in the code some line is printed to logs, and I want to find out where. Usually I just search the codebase for that string, but now that string is generated dynamically, so is not searchable.

And I wander if there is any way to run python in some debug mode, and tell it to stop when some pattern will appear in sdout, and then print location in code where it stopped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about replacing `sys.stdout`?

For example:

```
import sys
import traceback


class StacktraceOnPrint:

    def __init__(self, orig_stdout, substring):
        self.orig_stdout = orig_stdout
        self.substring = substring

    def write(self, txt):
        if self.substring in txt:
            traceback.print_stack() # OR  import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        self.orig_stdout.write(txt)


sys.stdout = StacktraceOnPrint(sys.stdout, 'blah')
print 'test ...'
print 'Hello blah.'
print 'test ...'
```

**NOTE** [`traceback.print_stack`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_stack) uses `sys.stderr`. If you want to catch `sys.stderr`, use different function (like [`traceback.format_stack`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_stack)). Otherwise it recurses forever; causes `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` ..

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pdb module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html).
This will give you the possibility to interactively debug your code while running.
You can probably write a script that runs your program "step-by-step" until you read that line in the log file.

Comment: Tried it and gived up after third hour of debugging. :( 

Just joking. It probably will take years in my project to find that line in such a way.

Comment: You don't have do to it "by-hand". Write a script to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

you can include pathname, module, funcName, line number for each log record by setting formatter

```
formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] p%(process)s {%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d} %(levelname)s - %(message)s','%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Did that, but that output is not probably not from logger.

Comment: if the output is from print statement try [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/145297-grabbing-the-current-line-number-easily/)

Comment: But you need to know on which line to insert that call, which tells on which line it was called. What a paradox. :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using twisted. You can start your twisted program under `pdb`. Check `twistd --help`:

```
...
-b, --debug            run the application in the Python Debugger (implies
                       nodaemon), sending SIGUSR2 will drop into debugger
...
```

After you start the program under `pdb` you can put breakpoints where you like. You can also specify condition for the breakpoint to be honored:

```
(Pdb) b myfunc, somecondition
```

But in your particular case it looks it is quite hard to detect a place where to break the program.

So you might consider another approach. For example, you could redirect logs to stdin of some script. This script watches for the certain log line. When it detects the line in question, the script sends `SIGUSR2` to the twisted program, and it will drop into the debugger. After that just inspect your program with `pdb`.